# Component Metadata in the Configuration File

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, lightning-community

I am building some Lightning Web Components for a Community for the first time and would like to add Config data to the Metadata file. What needs to be done to allow admins to be able to for example: choose background color or hide a button.

I understand that something similar to below should be added to the metadata file. What would need to be added to the JS & HTML file?

```
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
        <property name="backgroundColor" type="Color" default="#ff00ff"></property>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a property with @api annotated with same same name you have in configuration file.

So in your component-name.js file, You need to add below property to get the value from community builder.

```
@api backgroundColor;
```

You can further use the property in your html file as per requirement.